# Check if the client is on the front page?

Tags: php

How can I check if the client is on the front page?

What I've tried

```
$CURRENT_URL = "http://". $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if($CURRENT_URL == "http://domain.com")
{
...
}
```

Comment: And?  Did that work? If not, what happened?

Comment: Why not just add `$is_front_page=true` on your `index.php` file, and then use `if(isset($is_front_page))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check the request URI:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] === "/")
```

Answer (score 1):

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` will always begin with a `/`. Even if you are on the *home page*. So you'll add this slash the domain you are testing against:

```
$CURRENT_URL = "http://". $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if($CURRENT_URL == "http://domain.com/") { // ...
```